# How to unzip docx file using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

How to unzip docx file using C#?

Comment: How is it compressed? Do the reverse.

Comment: To extract the bytes into your garbage bin?

Comment: any trys to be shown here?

Comment: Word document is not an archived file. What do you mean by uncompress / decompress ?

Comment: I want to extract its XML

Comment: Word document docx is actually a zip file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new Office file extensions (docx,potx,xlsx,etc) turning into zip files when they are uploaded to a web server and then downloaded.

These file formats are now using an Open XML file format system so they are more compatible with other office programs from Google, Open Office...etc. Essentially they are zip files that are full of XML files that when opened with a proper application turn into a friendly word document.

I stole this full of shame from [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?162526-Is-your-docx-file-turning-into-a-zip-SOLUTION) where you can find full info.

I hope this answer will help you and all the ignorant people that made fun of you and negative voting your question without even knowing the answer.

Comment: While this provides good information, that blog post you have referenced deals more with web server inability to serve the correct MIME type for the Open XML based Office documents back in 2007 :) To work with these files properly and not reinvent the wheel, Open XML SDK is the way to go.

Comment: @David Khaykin You are right, but I just wanted to give him a hint that indeed these files may be zip files.

Comment: @Dummy01 I wonder if you can send the link again for the answer. because it seems the link is not redirecting properly

Answer (score 4):

If you mean `docx` files, they're basically just `zip` files created with a particular convention.

Look into the [Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code that you are looking for. I have used this class for docx zip and unzip operations.

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using Microsoft.Deployment.Compression;
   using Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Zip;


 namespace <YourPackage>.Libs
 {
 public class ZipFile
 {
    private string _zipfilepath;

    public ZipFile(string zipfilepath)
    {
        _zipfilepath = zipfilepath;
    }

    public void Compress(string filePath,bool deleteSourceFolder)
    {
        var filePaths = new List<string>();

        if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            filePaths.AddRange(Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(filePath).ToList());
        }

        if (filePaths.Count > 0)
        {
            var zip = new ZipInfo(_zipfilepath);
            zip.Pack(filePath, true, CompressionLevel.None, null);
        }

        if(deleteSourceFolder)
            Directory.Delete(filePath,deleteSourceFolder);
    }

    public void Uncompress(string destinationPath)
    {
        var zip = new ZipInfo(_zipfilepath);
        zip.Unpack(destinationPath);
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you get the Microsoft.Deployment namespaces?  I have all the default references, but Microsoft doesn't have a Deployment namespace.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You have to install [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/). If you are looking to modify a word document, I can highly recommend  [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Set reference to System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.
Then something like this:

```
using System.IO.Compression;

string zipPath = @"c:\tmp\Test.docx";
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
   archive.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath + ".unzipped");
}
```

Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh485709(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx (ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory Method)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Install the Open XML SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124 and use this to work with the XML inside the Docx files.