# Can i retrieve images and shapes from word file and display them in PictureBox control of C#?

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, shapes

I want to extract images and shapes from word file and display them in picturebox control of C#.Is it possible? and if its then how ? i am searching it for many days but didn't find any solution. So plz help me

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with MS Word documents in Open Office XML format (e.g. .docx files) you could try reading them out of the file directly. The .docx file is just a zip file and the images are contained in a media directory inside them. [This page](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/About-Microsoft-Open-Office-Xml-document-format.aspx) has more information on the file format.[1](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/About-Microsoft-Open-Office-Xml-document-format.aspx)

Alternatively I guess you could try automating Word using COM, to open the file and then retrieve the image that way. This approach has the disadvantage of spawning an instance of Word.

Either method will involve more detailed steps than I've described here, but should be do-able.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it without going in to the trouble of using OpenXML or word interop libs.
This is what you need to do.

1. Rename your MyDoc.docx file with MyDoc.zip.
2. Then unzip the contents. You will get a very specific folder structure. 
   Ex: _rels, docProps,word, [Content_Types].xml
3. Go into word folder
4. Inside the word folder you will see a folder called media. That's where your images are.
5. Now you should be able to read and load these images in to picture boxes.

Comment: Just noticed Chris Spicer has already answered your question. Anyways hope my reply helps.

Comment: but after renaming the MyDoc.zip file still has the same extension .docx when i see the properties.winzipp is necessary to be installed?

Comment: Have you tried doing these steps manually? You should try these steps manually first and then try to code. I am not sure about winzip. Just use windows default zip compression and extract Word Part files. Have a look at my reply on unzipping docx files here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240693/how-to-unzip-docx-file-using-c/16932622#16932622

Comment: Are you sure it is a docx file(not a doc file)? If so there is absolutely no reason for it to behave differently. If it is a doc file first you need to save it as a docx file in MSWord.