# Extract images from word file in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a problem in image extraction. I have written this code to extract all images from word file but this code works for some images means it does save some image files but on the other hand this code does not extract images from Word file. I'm using office interop library.

```
    protected void ExtractImage(string imagename, int imagenum)
    {

        word.InlineShape shape = oword.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[imagenum];
        int dones = oword.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count;           //Counts number of images in word document
        for(int i =1 ; i <= dones; i++)
        {
            shape = oword.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[i];
            shape.Select();
            oword.Selection.Copy();

            if (Clipboard.GetDataObject() != null)
            {
                IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Bitmap image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)data.GetData(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
                    image.Save(@"C:\Upload2\" + imagename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: *" it does save some image files but on the other hand this code does not extract images from Word file"* - So does it or doens't it exatract the images? Your question is vague.

Comment: I'm reading word files from a folder and extracting all images from it. This code 80% times extract all images but 20% times it misses the images from file.

Comment: Yes, i'm just reading docx files.

Comment: How to deal word file as a zip file?

Comment: ExtractImage(Last_File_count+"-"+Image_naming + ".jpg", Image_index);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip docx file using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240693/how-to-unzip-docx-file-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like messing with the Clipboard because the user might be using it...

So, instead I did this using the following code:

```
private IEnumerable<Image> GetImagesFromXml(string xml)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
    var images = doc.Descendants(ns + "part").Where(a => a.Attribute(ns + "contentType") != null && a.Attribute(ns + "contentType").Value.Contains("image"))
    .Select(a => new { Name = a.Attribute(ns + "name").Value, Type = a.Attribute(ns + "contentType").Value, D64 = a.Descendants(ns + "binaryData").First().Value, Compression = a.Attribute(ns + "compression").Value });

    return images.Select(i => Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(i.D64)), false, false));
}
```